# SQL Query conditional select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write query so that if the column contains a dash, it gives one result, else it gives another result.

My query is shown below.

I get error:
Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view '#MyTEmp' because it is not full-text indexed.

I don't know what this means or how to fix it...

Here is the query code I would like to get to work:

```
Select ( IIF( CONTAINS(PONO, '-'),'Dashwala',PONO)), Qty from #MyTEmp
```

And...

**#MyTEmp was gotten like this:**

```
Select  AR_Numbers, PONO, Product, Sum( isnull(try_cast(quantity as decimal ), 0)) as Qty 
into #MyTemp
from 
(Select ARs.DocID, Ars.Field61 as AR_Numbers, PONOs.Field21 as PONO, CoreData.Field9 as Product, CoreData.Field10 as Quantity 
from ssMVFields ARs left join ssFields PONOs on ARs.DocId = PONOs.DocId left join ssField14 as CoreData on Ars.DocID = CoreData.DocID  
where ARs.ArchiveID = 12 and PONOs.ArchiveID = 12 and CoreData.ArchiveID = 12) as AAA
Group by AR_Numbers, PONO, Product
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try CHARINDEX function instead, CONTAINS is a Full-Text Search function

```
select 
    case when CHARINDEX('-', PONO) > 0 then 'Dashwala' else PONO end, 
    Qty 
from 
    #MyTEmp
```

Answer (score 0):

For using function CONTAINS or FREETEXT you have to install Full-Text component on your sql server, your database must have Fulltext catalog and your tables must have indexed columns. Only after that you can using this functions for seeking predicates. 
Just for you - #MyTEmp must have be indexed as this - [How to create full-text index](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317(v=sql.105).aspx)

More about this technology: [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search)